# Unable to fetch contact Name from case using apex list. How do I do this?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, trigger, soql, visualforce-component

I am trying to fetch contact names from case object using apex class but instead of contact name its giving me contactId. Please help me to fetch Contact Name.

**Expected Output:** DEBUG|(Case:{Name=SomeName, CaseNumber=00001032, Status=New, Id=5005g000009pWu5AAE}

**Actual Output:** DEBUG|(Case:{ContactId=0035g000009ofFFAAY, CaseNumber=00001032, Status=New, Id=5005g000009pWu5AAE}

Here is my apex class code:

```
public with sharing class Report {
    public Report() {

    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Case> fetchRecords(){
        List<Case> caseList = new List<Case>();
        try {
            caseList = [SELECT Contact.Name, CaseNumber, Status  FROM Case];
            System.debug(caseList);
            return caseList;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.debug(sObject)` does not show parent or child relationships, only direct fields. The value is being queried, and is available in memory, but will not be output in a `System.debug` statement unless you somehow serialize the record:

```
System.debug(JSON.serializePretty(caseList));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @sfdcfox. Didn't knew that ```System.debug```  does not show parent or child relationships. Just learnt something new from you. :)

Comment: @user9824674 You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can be tried:

```
list<case> caseList = [SELECT id, contactid, CaseNumber, Status  FROM 
Case];
//System.debug(caseList);

list <ID> conID = new list<ID>();

for (Case cse:caseList )
{
conID.add(cse.contactid);
}

map<id,contact> conMap= new map<id,contact>( [select name from contact 
where id in : conID]);
//system.debug(conMap);

map<case,contact> caseConMap = new map<case,contact>();

for (case cs: caseList)
{
if (conMap.containskey(cs.contactid))
{
    caseConMap.put(cs, conMap.get(cs.contactid));
}
}
system.debug(caseConMap);
```